# how to browse and upload files in Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, file-upload

How to upload a file in windows phone i mean which controls are used to browse the files (phone Content) are they pre-defined for windows phone or do we need to create manually. Browsing them and uploading them .

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn594542.aspx

Comment: maybe this can help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202959(v=vs.105).aspx for background file transfers for Windows Phone 8

Answer (score 2):

you can try the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659730.aspx) way

1. Make sure that the user has consented to the required scope, and then create an upload
2. Handle pending uploads when the app restarts.

> ```
> private async void Upload()
> {
>     try
>     {
>         // Ensure that the user has consented to the wl.skydrive and wl.skydrive_update scopes.
>         var authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
>         var authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update" });
>         if (authResult.Session != null)
>         {
>             var liveConnectClient = new LiveConnectClient(authResult.Session);
>
>             // Upload to OneDrive.
>             LiveUploadOperation uploadOperation = await liveConnectClient.CreateBackgroundUploadAsync(
>                 uploadPath, fileName, uploadInputStream, OverwriteOption.Rename);
>             LiveOperationResult uploadResult = await uploadOperation.StartAsync();
>             HandleUploadResult(uploadResult);
>         }
>     }
>     catch (LiveAuthException ex)
>     {
>         // Handle errors.
>     }
>     catch(LiveConnectException ex)
>     {
>         // Handle errors.
>     }
> }
>
>
>
>
> var pendingOperations = await LiveConnectClient.GetCurrentBackgroundUploadsAsync();
> foreach(LiveDownloadOperation pendingOperation in pendingOperations)
> {
>     try
>     {
>         var opResult = await pendingOperation.AttachAsync();
>         // Handle results.
>     }
>     catch
>     {
>         // Handle errors.
>     }
> }
> ```